# Why my Xcode interface builder show red block and failed to render

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

## Problem

I have a Controller in Storyboard which has a long UIScrollView inside. Previously it shows perfectly in Interface Builder and now I haven't changed the code. The last time I knew that I updated Xcode to version 11.0. I don't quite know why it fails to render, is it some issue in Xcode 11?

If I compiled, it's success with 0 error and some warning (Which seems me to some Swift deprecated). Even it shows perfectly in Compiled App. I have tried:

1. Clean Build
2. Delete Derived Data
3. Reopen Xcode
4. Rebuild
5. Restart OS

[image: Some failed render screenshot]

## Edited after some experiment

Okay, so I tried a bunch of things again and I think I narrowed some problem (maybe?). So my layout show perfectly in `iPhone 11` preview, but it fail to render in `iPhone 11 Pro Max`, `iPhone 11 Pro` and `iPhone 8 Plus` preview. Is it ringing any bell?

**iPhone 11 screenshot:**
[image: iPhone 11 screenshot]

**iPhone 11 Pro Max screenshot:**
[image: iPhone 11 Pro Max screenshot]

**iPhone 8 Plus screenshot:**
[image: iPhone 8 Plus]

Comment: Had a similar issue: solution is here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58594124/why-have-my-storyboards-gone-red-in-xcode-11-1

Answer (score 1):

Obviously a change in storyboard previews in Xcode. Seems like it's no longer acceptable to show "simulated size: freeform" greater than iPhone screen height. Changing it to "simulated size: fixed" in Size Inspector solves the issue, and you can now scroll from within the reduced size window in storyboards view...