# Why have my .storyboards gone red in Xcode 11.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard

Just updated to Mac OS X Catalina (10.15) and Xcode 11.1, and some of my storyboards have gone red. All graphics appear to be there but, everything is RED. VERY red (as you can see below).

They still publish OK and this isn't a problem on Xcode 11.0 on a OS X Mojave (10.14.6) on my MacBook Pro?

Anyone? Thx

[image: RED storyboard view][image: With everything selected...]

Comment: Have you got any solution for this? I am also facing similar kind of issue.

Comment: No solutions yet... Updating to Xcode 11.2 doesn't fix it 

Comment: Xcode 11.2.1 - problem persists... 

Answer (score 1):

Obviously a change in storyboard previews in Xcode. Seems like it's no longer acceptable to show "simulated size: freeform" greater than iPhone screen height. Changing it to "simulated size: fixed" in Size Inspector solves the issue, and you can now scroll from within the reduced size window in storyboards view...

A change for the better? Let's see what happens...

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but mine did the same thing and I want to help others who stumble on this issue. Below the storyboard section you can change the type of phone you are using. I changed mine from iPhone 13 to a different one and changed it back and it went back to normal.